# Shell script fucntion oputput

Tags: linux, bash, shell

During my free time I have tried to create my private repo that contain all my .dotfiles so I can easily set my my working environment. As one of steps I want to automate installation of basic applications ie. Codium.
To do this I have created 2 shell scripts one containing steps needed to install codium 
`VSCodium.sh`

```sh
GPG=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/vscodium.gpg
REPO=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscodium.list 
wget -qO - https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/-/raw/master/pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo dd of=$GPG
if [ -f "$REPO" ]; then
    echo "Repository $REPO exist, skipping."
else
    echo 'deb https://paulcarroty.gitlab.io/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/debs/ vscodium main' | sudo tee --append $REPO
fi    
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -y codium
```

second one as wrapper function to give user control if he want to install that application

`confirm`

```sh
confirm() {
    local message=${1:?Must provide an message.}
    local installation=${2:?Must provide installation script path}
    local falied=${3:-Incorrect response. Exiting}
    read -rp "$message " response
    case "$response" in
        [yY])
            chmod 755 $installation 
            $installation | sh
            ;;
        *)
            $falied
            ;;
    esac
}
```

On their own executed `VSCodium.sh` work fine.
function `confirm` connected with simple `echo "hello world"` script also work fine

`confirm 'Do you want start? ' hello.sh 'exiting'`

However if I connect `confirm` and `VSCodium.sh` together 
`confirm "Do you want install VSCodium [y/n] " ~/.dotfiles/apps/VSCodium.sh "Skiping VSCodium installation."`
Installation is successful but my output is quite messed up

```
Do you want install VSCodium [y/n]  y
4+1 records in
4+1 records out
2256 bytes (2,3 kB, 2,2 KiB) copied, 0,35326 s, 6,4 kB/s
sh: 1: Repository: not found
sh: 2: Hit:1: not found
sh: 3: Hit:2: not found
sh: 4: Hit:3: not found
sh: 5: Get:4: not found
sh: 6: Get:5: not found
sh: 7: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
E: Write error - write (32: Broken pipe)
```

As I am beginner in shell scripting I can't find an issue.

Comment: What does `installation` contain? We can't provide a certain answer unless we know what its value will be. That said, running an unquoted `$cmd` is basically always wrong; see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @stackinside, if it is indeed what the OP wants (if `installation` is indeed a filename), that would be better written as `sh <"$installation"` or `sh "$installation"`; no good reason to use `cat`.

Comment: @stackinside, I consider `'curl http://example.com/installme'` to also be an "installation script path" in a meaningful way, and that would explain why the OP would think `$installation | ...` should work. I don't believe a local file is the only option.

Comment: Beyond that, `cat file | ...` is a habit worth breaking. Consider `cat file | tail`, forcing the entire file to be read, whereas `tail <file` or `tail file` can jump straight to the end. Lots of similar cases -- `sort` can parallelize with a seekable descriptor but not with a FIFO from cat; `wc -c` can use `stat()` to return in constant time with a real file but has to read actual file content front-to-end (making performance O(n) instead of O(1)) when given a FIFO instead; etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `$installation` is path to installation script like provided example `VSCodium.sh` 
So basic `$installation | sh` is equal  `~/.dotfiles/apps/VSCodium.sh | sh`

Comment: @Niviral, but `~/.dotfiles/apps/VSCodium.sh | sh` is **wrong**. It tries to run the **output** of `VSCodium.sh` as if that output were a script itself, which is why you're getting all those errors (from the copy of `sh` on the right-hand side of the pipeline trying to treat the script's output as another script).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you! Your answer was really helpful! I also found few issues with sourcing function but was able to resolve them. It is working as I wanted.